# Scripting: updating scripts

Tags: python, blender

I am completely new to python and I'm just trying it out. Something is confusing me for hours until I finally made this little test.

I have 2 scripts, a.py and b.py

```
#a.py 
num = 3 

#b.py 
import a 

print(a.num)
```

When b.py is ran, this prints 3. But if I change the value of num to any other number, the output is still 3.

How can I resave / update my script files?

Comment: Yes you can save your files - you will have to do this before running your scripts again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python will only read the module file on the first time the module is imported. So what you are editing is still the old version of the imported objects. If you want to reload a module, you can use `imp.reload`. For more clarification, you can read [When I edit an imported module and reimport it, the changes don’t show up. Why does this happen?](http://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#when-i-edit-an-imported-module-and-reimport-it-the-changes-don-t-show-up-why-does-this-happen).

Comment: So during the development of my project, I have to include imp.reload on the imported modules?? and remove them when the project is finished? This is a hassle.

Comment: If you want to reload, you have to. Or you have to terminate your current script, update the imported module, and run the script again. But I think the num should be a fixed number, you don't have to change it in file but change it when you need to in logic.

Comment: The above code is just a sample. I'm talking about developing real projects. But never mind.

Answer (score 1):

To reload a module, use `imp.reload()` from the `imp` module. See http://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html#imp.reload

Answer (score 0):

How do you run `b.py`? As a side note remove *.pyc files before running script again.

Comment: Via Run Script button. What are pyc files? Where can I find them? I'm sorry. I just started with scripting.

Answer (score 0):

```
#a.py 
num = 3 

#b.py 
import a 

print(a.num) # result is 3
a.num += 1
print(a.num) # result is 4
```

Next time you run b.py, result is the same.

Because a.num is always init as 3, so you maybe need to update the raw a.py file to change 3 to some other values.

But this is wired I suggest not do so.